# optimizing the time for get requests to a server in python

Tags: python, multithreading, get, query-optimization

I have to fetch a large list of image url's from a csv and generate get requests for those urls. Currently I am able to have a output of 50 urls i 17s. I want to have these 50 image urls in 5s. How can I optimize by get request? I have read that one way would be to do multithreading by I have no idea of integrating it into my code?

**code**

```
 import pandas as pd
import requests
auth_token = 'Wy'

df=pd.read_csv('/instaurls.csv')
for row in df.itertuples():
    url =row[1]
    resp = requests.get('http://predict/ethnicity?auth_token=%s&url=%s' % (auth_token, url))
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Look into grequests: https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests. I've used it before do many requests at once and it worked fine for me. It seems they are directing people to request-threads (https://github.com/requests/requests-threads) and requests-futures (https://github.com/ross/requests-futures), so these all may be worth looking into.

Comment: @greenthumbtack they only with python 3 and i am unfortunatley i am using 2..7 and cannot upgrade to 3 for project specific reasons. will and how multi threading support me?